# npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher

Tags: npm, uuid

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to install the firebase in my ubuntu.

I used the command: `sudo npm install - firebase cli`, but I am not able the log in as it is saying firebase command not found.

Answer (score 21):

Basically, the error suggests you should upgrade [`uuid@3.4.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid/v/3.4.0) version to 7 or [higher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

Below is the message of the package author on the deprecation;

> Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

Based on your package manager preference, you can run either of the commands below so as to upgrade to the latest stable version of [`uuid`](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#quickstart).

```bash
# npm
npm install uuid@latest

# yarn
yarn add uuid@latest

# pnpm
pnpm add uuid@latest
```

Comment: it is not required `-g` flag (global install)?

Comment: Use the `-g` flag for global (no need to be at the root of any project). When not specified, it applies to your current project (should be executed at the root of your project in this case).

Comment: Didn't work, looks like I am facing similar to this issue (still open): https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/2151

Comment: `npm install uuid@latest` didn't work for me because I still get the same warning re `uuid v3.4.0`

Answer (score 6):

try this
`npm install uuid@7.0.3 --force`

Comment: don't work here =(

Comment: Doesn't work as well. So even with the latest version (`8.3.2`) in my dependencies I'm still being asked to upgrade it from `3.4.0` at least up to `7`.

Comment: looks like, this issue is still open: https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/2151

Answer (score 3):

DO `npm cache clean --force` and than `npm install uuid@7.0.3 --force`

work for me